# How to delete an item from SQLite angularJS

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I'm working on ionic project where I have view that has a button to delete a contact from table contacts.

This is the view:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="item in list" class="item-remove-animate" item="item" >
        {{ item.firstname }} 
        {{ item.lastname}} 
        <ion-option-button class="button-royal" ng-click="edit($index)"> 
            Edit 
        </ion-option-button>
        <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="del(item)"> 
            delete 
        </ion-option-button>        
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

This is the button to delete the contact:

```
<ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="del(item)">
```

The delete button will show a confirmation popup message, if the user confirms the delete, then current contact will be removed from the table `contacts` in the database.

This is the controller:

```
$scope.del = function(item) { 

    var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
     title: 'Delete contact', 
    template: 'Are you sure you want to delete?'    });

     confirmPopup.then(function(res) { 
    if(res) { 

    var query = "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE id = (?)";
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [item.id]);
      $state.go($state.current, $stateParams, {reload: true, inherit: false});

 };
```

The contact is not deleted, when I insert the ID manually like this:

```
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [1]);
```

It works, else it does not, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

can you please try with following -

```
var query = "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE id = ?";
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [item.id]);
```